# Difference Between Windows 8 Store App and Windows 8 Desktop Application

Tags: windows-8

What is the difference between Windows 8 Store App and Windows 8 Desktop Application.  Can I use Javascript to create Windows 8 Desktop Application.  I found an [article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ultrabook-and-tablet-windows-8-sensors-development-guide/) from Intel which give some difference between these two applications.   But it is not clear

Comment: One is a tablet interface and the other is the traditional desktop.  The desktop has all the same stuff as before and Store Apps can be done in C++/xaml, C#/xaml, html/js and (please don't do this) VB/xaml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 8 Desktop Application
- You can download the softwares and install it . No Marketplace required
- Traditional development tools like C# , C++ , Winforms , WPF etc

Windows 8 Store App
- You can install it only via Windows Store and uploading the app to the store will undergo certification process.
- YOu can develop using XAML with C#/VB.NET/C++ , HTML/JavaSCript/CSS , Embarcadero Prism etc.
- Designed mainly for **Touch**

Comment: Thanks @Senthil Kumar B for this clarification, I was not aware that Windows Store App can be installed only via Windows Store, I had a wrong impression that Windows Store Apps can be installed offline.

Comment: You also have to distinguish this: desktop applications don't work on windows rt. Only windows store apps will work on "rt" devices.

Comment: You can install a Windows Store App without going through the store, here's how: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh852635.aspx

Answer (score 3):

no you can't use javascript to write you own desktop program.

Here a simple overview about both type:

**Windows 8 Desktop Application:**
That just the basic program like notepad, MS Word, AutoCad...
Writing in the know language such as C++, C# ...

**Windows 8 Store App**
Here you create app in that new start menu. Click on the button in the start menu to open you own app. Here you can write the app also in html5/javascript.

Comment: You can too use javascript to write a desktop program. For example, you can write a [HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or you can write a C++ application that manually hosts the javascript engine. Mind you, it's not a very common strategy on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can sideload Windows RT apps too, which is useful for LOB apps. Take a look at the Windows RT Development guide -

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30703

Section titled "Installing developer packages on Windows RT outside the Windows Store" (Pg 19)

HTH

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript can't be used to create a Desktop Application.

see ,desktop apps are those apps that required you to run Setup.exe file and were installed through a Pen drive or a CD or might be you got it from internet.

These apps run on operating system like Windows 7, Windows XP and gave you the full control on what you want to install and what not .

Windows 8 Metro apps are apps on your phone
This I am telling for real understanding.
You go to android store and download temple run for example.
The game is acceded from the online store and you have no discretion on it.similar way we have these metro apps

Comment: "JavaScript can't be used to create a Desktop Application."

This is not true: you can embed web browser inside your desktop app, and use HTML or JavaScript normally.